# JMS JNDI pool locked on server

Tags: spring-mvc, jms, websphere, connection-pooling, spring-jms

I was developing a simple Spring MVC application that invokes a Web Service over a JMS trasport. I need to deploy it on websphere application server. Everything seems to work fine when I reference the remote connection factory directly from my application, and even seems to work properly when I try to use a local JNDI Queue connection factory on my WAS, but then, I cannot shutdown my server.

It seems to be because its connections pool keeps locked by somebody. It never invokes Session.close over JMS session (it is managed by JAX-WS server framework, in this case Apache Axis2). I have done the same from an even simpler spring MVC application (just @Controller and views) and it stops fine. The application that makes pool to be locked just includes a more complex context with persistence and transaction management (annotation-driven).

Do you think that this transaction mananagement could affect JMS session management? Somebody have ever found a JMS connection pool locked by an spring application?
Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: This question is a little broad, it sounds like a race condition, but without more information it's difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I think that I have found why does it happen. We do ServletContext.close in our architecture classes (using a listener in web.xml). I think that you cannot close Servlet context programatically because it has to be done by Web Server, otherwise, it looses references and connection pools could be locked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That was the solution to avoid locking. We removed ServletContext.close, so our server can find the references to used resources, and can release connections on pool.